# Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Option 'agents_dir' missing in file - Rails 4 + Passenger deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, passenger

I have been banging my head against a door trying to deploy a Rails 4 app on Ubuntu 14 + Apache2 + Passenger. I seemed to have made some progress: passenger is installed properly with the proper apache modules, my apache conf files are set up, everything is restarted, etc.. when I go to my site I get a listing of my Rails App's public directory. I investigated the logs and found the following:

`Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Option 'agents_dir' missing in file '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini'`

I different SO post said something about mods-available stuff so here's `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf`:

`<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
</IfModule>`

And `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.load`:

`LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so`

What am I doing wrong? I'm going to kiss whoever solves this, I swear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into this problem and fixed it by reinstalling the `passenger` package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall passenger passenger-dev
```

Comment: Yes, i ended up running `sudo apt-get purge passenger passenger-dev apache2` to completely remove all of the packaged and then reinstalled and it worked properly. So, a reinstall was the easiest route.

Comment: Just found this due to the same problem.  It's caused by a not completely clean upgrade.  More importantly, this is only part of the fix - you need to complete *stop* and start the server again, a reload wouldn't fix things for me.  Ref:  https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1434

Answer (score 4):

**If you happen to have same issue while Upgrading Nginx and Passenger on Ubuntu 14.04**

```
sudo apt-get purge passenger
sudo apt-get remove nginx (it won't remove your config files)
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-full passenger
```

Answer (score 2):

`locations.ini` is a passenger + ngnix config related item, and does not apply for passenger + apache config.

See the [Phusion Passenger users guide, Apache version](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html) for details about how to configure passenger with apache.

Or see [Phusion Passenger users guide, Nginx version](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) for configuring passenger with nginx.

If you are going the passenger + apache route, the key step you seem to be missing is to run `passenger-install-apache2-module` which provides the right values for `PassengerRoot`, `PassengerDefaultRuby`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, when I run that command I get `The Phusion Passenger Apache module is correctly installed :-)`. Additional help would be appreciated! Come to think of it, I think I may have initially set it up for nginx, but decided to switch to apache. Perhaps the apache passenger installation didn't override some of the nginx passenger installation?

Comment: The users guide I linked is fairly detailed; please follow the steps detailed there, restarting from scratch if need be. Running `passenger-install-apache2-module` should give correct value to specify for `PassengerRoot` instead of the totally incorrect `..../locations.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a fresh Apache/Passenger setup on Ubuntu 14.04 and ran into this. I have built this same setup at least a dozen times.

My `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf`:

```
### Begin automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby
</IfModule>
### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###
```

My `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini`:

```
[locations]
packaging_method=deb
bin_dir=/usr/bin
support_binaries_dir=/usr/lib/passenger/support-binaries
lib_dir=/usr/lib/passenger
helper_scripts_dir=/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts
resources_dir=/usr/share/passenger
include_dir=/usr/share/passenger/include
doc_dir=/usr/share/doc/passenger
ruby_libdir=/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
node_libdir=/usr/share/passenger/node
apache2_module_path=/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so
ruby_extension_source_dir=/usr/share/passenger/ruby_extension_source
nginx_module_source_dir=/usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module
```

So, yeah, the locations.ini absolutly contains Apache configuration information ...but this file is identical on all my machines working or not.

Reinstalling via `--reinstall` didn't work ...so I `purge`d everything.

```
sudo apt-get purge passenger passenger-dev \ 
                   libapache2-mod-passenger \
                   apache2 apache2-threaded-dev;
sudo apt-get autoremove;
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2;
```

Then reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-threaded-dev \
                     libapache2-mod-passenger;

sudo a2enmod rewrite expires deflate passenger status;
sudo apache2ctl restart;
```

Validated install:

```
sudo passenger-config validate-install;
```

And confirmed that Passenger was running:

```
sudo passenger-memory-stats;
```

Then, finally, re-enabled my app's Apache config. One last `sudo apache2ctl restart` and I'm happily running!

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

$ passenger --version
Phusion Passenger version 5.0.15
```